# How to loop files and get one based on a value from a remote ftp server. [.bat]

Tags: batch-file, command-line, batch-processing

**Context:**

I have .bat script that connects to a ftp server and searches for a file.
Files are stored weekly in this ftp directory, and uses the following file name convention:

currentYear+currentYearWeek.LOG -> e.g: 202310.LOG

My script tries to get the latest file stored there using the naming convention by building the file name(getting the current year and current week and then concatenate this values to have 202310.LOG) and then search for it.

**Problem**

The problem here is that if the latest file hasn't been stored and there is no 202310.LOG file, I would like to get the previous one to read it's metadata and see how old is this file. Eg:

```
set filename=GetCurrentYEar()GetCurrentWeek().LOG
rem Imagine filename value is: 202310.LOG

IF(filename does not exists) (
  rem Then look for the latest filename(which seemingly is 202309.LOG or 202308.LOG if both of these exists, just get me latest one that is 202309.LOG) < %filename% 

)
```

I was thinking about using a for loop to loop the file in that directory and check the files individually but I don't know how to make it work it file on a remote ftp server. Any ideas on how to approach this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
set /a filename=202310
:retry
if exist %filename%.log goto found
set /a filename-=1
if "%filename:~-2%"=="00" set /a filename-=47
goto retry
:found
echo filename is %filename%.log
```

[not actually tested]

If the name does not exist, then subtract one from it.
If the result has `00` as its last 2 characters, then subtract a further 47, so 202301 (missing) -> 202300 -> 202253